# I send message by kafka-producer in multi-threads, but message loss occurred

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using kafka-producer and sending data to topic 'test-topic' that consist of replication-factor 3 and partitions 1 in kafka-cluster(consisting of three brokers).

I created five thread. each thread sent 10,000 messages(each message size is 4000 bytes).

i expected latest offset 50,000 but actually 44,993.

about 5,000 messages loss occurred.

Why did message loss occur? Below my codes... (KAFKA-VERSION 1.1.0)

> KafkaMessageSender.class

```
public class KafkaMessageSender {
    private final static Logger logger = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageSender.class);
    private Properties props;
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
    private String topic;
    private AtomicInteger count;

    public KafkaMessageSender(AtomicInteger count, String bootstrapUrls, String topic) {
        logger.info("KafkaMessageSender initializing...");
        this.topic = topic;
        this.count = count;
        props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapUrls);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384); //16384
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 5);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        logger.info("KafkaMessageSender initializing end");     

    }

    public void sendMessages() {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, Messages.MSG_4K)); //Messages.MSG_4K indicates 4000bytes message
        count.getAndIncrement();
        logger.info("count : "+count.get());
    }
}
```

> KafkaMessageSenderMain.class

```
public class KafkaMessageSenderMain {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageSenderMain.class);

    final static String bootstrap_url = "ism1.solulink.co.kr:9092,ism2.solulink.co.kr:9092,ism3.solulink.co.kr:9092";
    final static String topic = "test-topic"; //topic name
    final static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final static int MAX_LOOP = 10000; //message sending count
    final static int MAX_THREAD = 5;  //created number of threads

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD);
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() ->{
                    KafkaMessageSender sender = new KafkaMessageSender(count, bootstrap_url, topic);
                    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_LOOP; j++) {
                        sender.sendMessages(); //send message
                    }
            });
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            boolean flag = executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long procTime = (endTime - startTime);
            logger.info("all Threads is shutdown? : "+flag);
            logger.info("processTime : " + ((double)procTime/(double)1000L)+"sec");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("awaitTermination exception",e);
        }
    }
}
```

> Result

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B9oo.png)

Comment: Do you lose all messages towards the end, or all over the place?`producer.send` is asynchronous. You may have to wait for it to finish before shutting down everything.

Comment: You need to provide some more information. What if the value of `count` at the end? How did you determine the latest offset? And, you need to call `close()` on the producer when you're finished - it may or may not be the cause of your problem but you need to eliminate the possibility first.

Comment: i saw you already fixed the issue so my only comment is that it seams that you are creating a new producer instance in every thread. kafka producer is thread safe and it is better to share single producer instance between the threads to get better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify and run your code as below to see what the error is ?

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, Messages.MSG_4K), new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

Comment: according to your code. i change code. i saw the error. `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 3 record(s) for test-topic-0: 30001 ms has passed since last append`. what means it?

Comment: I found two things:
1. This error means that Producer is timing out (> 30000ms by default) while waiting for successful response from Kaka cluster. 
2. Your batch size is small compare with message size (Only 4 messages can be batched in one) so the speed of queueing batches is faster than the speed of sending batches to Kafka cluster. Then it leads to the issue 1 above. 
  
Can you play around with request.timeout.ms and batch.size configs by increasing the value of request.timeout.ms to 60000 (ms) and the value batch.size to 163840 (bytes), for example.

Comment: i changed `request.timeout.ms=1000000`. after that 5threads, 10threads and 30threads work well. but i have a question. Changing `request.timeout.ms` value higher become a problem?

Comment: I don't find upper bound of request.timeout.ms config in Kafka documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration), but it has lower bound is replica.lag.time.max.ms (a broker config). If we look Kafka configuration by eyes of Mathematician it is just like a multi-criteria optimization problem so throughput = f(x1, x2, x3, ...)  where x1 = request.timeout.ms, x2 = batch.size, x3 = linger.ms, etc.. I haven't found a proper solution for this but we are still able to tune performance depending on concrete scenario.